# DNSSEC- Client software

Tags: networking, dns

I'm interested in running DNSSEC, not sure how this works.  Does DNSSEC need to be supported both on the client and server. I currently have DNSSEC on my domain hosting site and the VPS server but if i transfer that to my home server. I would also have to provide DNSSEC on that server as well?  Do I need client software as well for windows or android to actually use DNSSEC?

If I have a basic client, which is browsing the web and other services, would that client need a DNSEC DNS caching (fowarding) server as well in particularly outside the network (cloud, VPS)?